# El asistente de Firebase no funciona

Tags: firebase, firebase-auth

He intentado reiniciar los plugins y aplicarlos, pero sigue sin funcionar. Se queda cargando todo el rato, pero no consigue conectar con los servicios. También he cambiado de red wifi por si eres problema de esto, pero nada. Adjunto captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo lo que he hecho ha sido cambiar de versión deAndroid Studio, ya que parece que en Arctic Fox no funciona el asistente de firebase.